# How to focus ListView's TextCell by button?

Tags: c#, listview, button, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need to focus TextCells one by one via a button click.
I tried listView.ScrollTo.

```
private void Button_Clicked_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listViewJson.ItemTapped += ListViewJson_ItemTapped;
}

private void ListViewJson_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
    var focusing = e.Item;
    listViewJson.ScrollTo(focusing, ScrollToPosition.MakeVisible, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, try to define an index to detect which cell to be selected. Then change the index via button click like:

```
int selectedIndex = 0;
private void MyBtn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (selectedIndex == dataList.Count) selectedIndex = 0;
    myListView.SelectedItem = dataList[selectedIndex++];
}
```

when the TextCell is selected the ListView's ItemSelected event will fire, you can put your code in it like:

```
private void MyListView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //try to do something
}
```

Here is my code behind for you referring to:

```
ObservableCollection<string> dataList = new ObservableCollection<string>();

int selectedIndex = 0;

public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        dataList.Add("item" + i);
    }

    myListView.ItemsSource = dataList;

    myListView.ItemSelected += MyListView_ItemSelected;

    MyBtn.Clicked += MyBtn_Clicked;
}

private void MyListView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //try to do something
}

private void MyBtn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (selectedIndex == dataList.Count) selectedIndex = 0;
    myListView.SelectedItem = dataList[selectedIndex++];
}
```